# Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, java-bytecode-asm

I am developing a small Spring application. I have to store the details of the student information in the database. I have developed one SimpleFormController. I have used NetBeans + Hibernate mapping + Spring. When I deploy the project, the following errors occurs.

**My spring-config-db-applicationContext.xml is shown below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <value>${driverClassName}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <value>${url}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2">
        <value>${username}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3">
        <value>${password}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>


  <bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <!-- <property name="configLocation">
        <value>WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property> -->
    <property  name="mappingResources" >
        <list>
            <value>hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

  <!--  <property  name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property> -->

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
  <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>-->
        </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

**Following error is occurs:**

```
ERROR (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:213) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jndi:/localhost/Student/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring-db-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:286)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:526)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:730)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:387)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:270)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:627)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:511)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1231)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1471)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:824)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:350)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:302)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:61)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:238)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:813)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:731)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1454)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1392)
        ... 48 more
Mar 12, 2010 5:32:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Comment: I have included asm.jar and cglib.jar

Comment: What is the value of `{$dialect}`?

Comment: dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect is defined in the jdbc.properties class

Comment: `asm-all.jar` is not enough information, we need to know what version of ASM it is.

Comment: I had this exception myself - pretty sure it's the wrong version of ASM

Comment: asm-all-2.2.3 is included....

Comment: Problem is solved.....
It is issue of the version of asm...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have an incompatibility between the version of ASM required by Hibernate (**asm-1.5.3.jar**) and the one required by Spring. But, actually, I wonder why you have asm-2.2.3.jar on your classpath (ASM is bundled in spring.jar and spring-core.jar to avoid such problems AFAIK). See [HHH-2222](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2222).

Comment: In my case, I had the wrong version of cglib.jar, but had the same exact error.  Now I have both cglib-2.1.3 and cglib-2.2 and it works.

Comment: cglib was the culprit for me. I had the correct version in the dependencies of my current project, but several other projects were bringing in lower versions of cglib as part of their maven dependencies. I had to add exclusions in maven for each one (I put this in an answer bleow)

Answer (score 17):

I found the solution to this problem here:
http://www.hildeberto.com/2008/05/hibernate-and-jersey-conflict-on.html

Comment: Summary of hildeberto.com: classloading issues with asm resolved using the cglib-nodep-*.jar. Hibernate is built against asm 1.5.3. The class loaders are picking up a much more recent version of asm and the class ClassWriter has been changed. Hibernate uses cglib under the covers, which in turn uses asm 1.5.3. This is the issue.  cglib-nodep was built to fix this issue. The asm classes have been moved from their standard package to a cglib package and it is these cglib versions that are used by the nodep library. Spring adopts a very similar approach.

Answer (score 7):

The [NoSuchMethodError](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) javadoc says this:

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.
>
> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

In your case, this Error is a *strong indication* that your webapp is using the wrong version of the JAR defining the `org.objectweb.asm.*` classes.

Comment: Thanks for the random downvote, especially considering that this answer is basically correct.

Comment: Correct but useless (NB: I am not the one who downvoted the answer)

Comment: @AlexeyTigarev - Why is it useless to understand what is causing the exception?  Why is it useless to explain the cause to the OP, who ... in the Question ... does not indicate that he understands what it means?

Comment: This is very useful at a time when everyone just address the issue and not why it is happening , this extract infact fix the issue 'Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.' which clearly means its high time you need to update your jar, mostly bcoz some changes in other dependencies, say the jre version.

Answer (score 7):

to resolve this kind of problem you should add two jar in your dependency POM (if use Maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: sorry i am not using maven

Comment: No problem you can improve my response to help the others which use Maven tools :)

Answer (score 3):

I change my APIs as 
* **cglib**  --- to ---> cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
* **cglib-asm**  --- to ---> cglib-asm.jar (i.e. latest one )

Comment: great boss solve error. but when i run the application "No input file specified" message display

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when initializing Spring on startup, using some different library versions, but everything worked when I got my versions in this order in the classpath (the other libraries in the cp were not important):

1. asm-3.1.jar
2. cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
3. asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

Update your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>asm</groupId>
  <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of incompatibility between different versions of cglib and lots of poor advice that can be googled on this subject (use ancient versions of cglib-nodeb, etc). After wrestling with this nonsense for 3 days with an ancient version of Spring (2.5.6)I have discovered:

- if Spring is throwing exceptions about NoSuchMethodError based on Enhancer from cglib missing setInterceptDuringConstruction(boolean), check your dependencies in maven (Dependency Hierarchy tab should list all the versions of cglib your project is polluted by). You probably have a dependency that is bringing in a pre-2.2 version of cglib, which Spring Cglib2AopProxy will grab Enhancer from to do the proxying. Add 2.2+ version to your dependencies but make sure to put in exclusions for these other versions. If you don't it will just keep blowing up.
- Make sure you have a high enough version of cglib in the current project's maven dependencies **but** beware of picking too high a version because then you'll get IncompatibleClassChangeError(s) instead.
- Verify that your pom changes have made it into the project correctly by doing a maven update on the project in question and then looking at Project > preferences > Java Build Path > Libraries > Maven Dependencies. If you see the wrong cglib versions in there, time to edit the pom again.

Comment: I'm happy you called it "nonsense." I do not like runtime dependencies. In other words, I do not like Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when added http-builder to dependencies.
In my case, I could solve by simply excluding asm like this:

```
compile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7'){
    excludes 'xml-apis'
    exclude(group:'xerces', module: 'xercesImpl')
    excludes 'asm'
}
```