# how call hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Tags: hibernate

hello friends i created struts with hibernate application when i call SessionFactory sessionFactory =new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session =sessionFactory.openSession();
this code is generate error please help me example code is here
this is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD                  3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
      <hibernate-configuration>
         <session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logintest</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxx</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
    </property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
```

and my mapping file  is here

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="net.model.Contact" table="contacts">
   <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
    <generator class="increment"></generator>
</id>   
<property name="firstName" column="firstname"></property>
<property name="lastName" column="lastname"></property>
 <property name="cellNo" column="cell_no"></property>
<property name="emailId" column="email_id"></property>
 <property name="birthDate" column="birthdate"/>
<property name="website" column="website"/>
  </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
```

mainclass is here

```
        public class Testmain {
       public static void main(String args[])
{
    Session session=null;
    try
    {
   SessionFactory sessionFactory =new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session =sessionFactory.openSession();

    Contact contact=new Contact();
   contact.setFirstName("mohan");
  contact.setLastName("raddy");
  contact.setEmailId("mm@gmail.com");
    contact.setCellNo("4664564564");
   contact.setWebsite("www.stackoverflow.com");
        session.save(contact);
       session.beginTransaction().commit();
      System.out.println("done");


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);
    }




    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Contact> contacts = null;
    try {

        contacts = (List<Contact>)session.createQuery("from Contact").list();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();


    for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        System.out.println(contact.getFirstName());
      System.out.println(contact.getLastName());
        System.out.println(contact.getEmailId());
          System.out.println(contact.getCellNo());
            System.out.println(contact.getWebsite());
    }   
   }}
```

following error showing when i run main class

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(Z)V
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
    at net.model.Testmain.main(Testmain.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Another clue may help - like the error you are getting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv) which suggests that you might be picking up the wrong version of asm.jar You should check your classpath and make sure you don't have multiple versions installed.