# Google App Engine -- NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, struts2, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to run a JSP in Google App Engine, and I am getting the following error message on my console.  Can anyone help?  I do have asm-3.3.jar in my classpath.

```
    WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:215)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<clinit>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1005)
    at com.configuration.ConfigurationListener.contextInitialized(ConfigurationListener.java:19)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:196)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:189)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:128)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:104)
```

Comment: a little more information will help especially the context you are working.i am not sure what you mean by running a jsp

Comment: I'm trying to launch the front page of my application, and I get this error.  I'm using Struts2 and Hibernate.

Comment: I don't think asm is whitelisted for AppEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added asm-1.5.2.jar (an earlier version), and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it's in your classpath for what Eclipse?  Do you have it in the WEB_INF/lib for your AE project?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Indigo, and yes, it's in WEB_INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this?

[Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv)

Specifically, it may be a problem with your cglib and asm-attrs versions.