# Beginner - Spring / hibernate integration, asm incompatibility

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm a beginner to spring/hibernate and try to run some simple web-application acceding the data on a remote db.

I'm using Netbeans 7.2 and the db is on Mysql 5.X

I've created a dummy 'User' table with 'id' and 'name' columns and few entries. I'm starting with an index page with a link to a user page getting the user info from the db. When i click on the link to user page i have the following error :

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Can someone help me?

NB: first sorry, sorry if i've done something wrong

Code :

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="userController" class="Controller.UserController" />

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="user.htm">userController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://******:3306/EPGV_Interface?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">*****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*****</property>
    <mapping resource="Model/User.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.reveng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN"     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="EPGV_Interface"/>
  <table-filter match-name="User"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package Model;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

User.java

```
package Model;
// Generated 13 nov. 2012 11:00:50 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA
/**
 * User generated by hbm2java
 */
public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
    public User() {
    }
    public User(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

User.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 13 nov. 2012 11:00:50 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Model.User" table="User" catalog="EPGV_Interface">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="45" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

UserController.java

```
package Controller;

import Model.HibernateUtil;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class UserController implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("user");
        try 
        {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            List result = session.createQuery(" from User").list();
            mv.addObject("users", result);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        return mv; 
    }
}
```

redirect.jsp :

```
<%--
Views should be stored under the WEB-INF folder so that
they are not accessible except through controller process.

This JSP is here to provide a redirect to the dispatcher
servlet but should be the only JSP outside of WEB-INF.
--%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %>
```

index.jsp :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Portail</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="user.htm">Go to user</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

user.jsp :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${user.id}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.name}"></c:out></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT : logs from the glassfish server admin console

My admin grant me the access to the log in glassfish admin console, here is what i obtained  for a 'session'

```
2740    INFO    Redirecting to /index.jsf(details)  org.glassfish.admingui  13 nov. 2012 17:49:17.005   _ThreadID=2631;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2741    INFO    Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...(details)  org.glassfish.admingui  13 nov. 2012 17:49:17.025   _ThreadID=2635;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2742    INFO    WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'(details)   javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web    13 nov. 2012 17:49:51.886   _ThreadID=2632;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2743    INFO    Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Nov 13 17:45:18 ... (details)   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext    13 nov. 2012 17:49:51.886   _ThreadID=2632;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2744    INFO    Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@44442f... (details)   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory    13 nov. 2012 17:49:51.887   _ThreadID=2632;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2745    INFO    WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext(details)     javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web    13 nov. 2012 17:49:51.890   _ThreadID=2632;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2746    INFO    Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 13 17:45:18 CET 2012]; root of context hie... (details)   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext    13 nov. 2012 17:49:51.890   _ThreadID=2632;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2747    INFO    Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@176be9... (details)   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory    13 nov. 2012 17:49:51.891   _ThreadID=2632;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2748    INFO    WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath(details)   javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web    13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.256   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2749    INFO    WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext(details)    javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web    13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.312   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2750    INFO    Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started(details)     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader   13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.312   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2751    INFO    Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 13 17:49:54 CET 2012]; root of context ... (details)   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext    13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.432   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2752    INFO    Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml](details)    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader   13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.503   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2753    INFO    Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory... (details)   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory    13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.572   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2754    INFO    Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 262 ms(details)     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader   13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.574   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2755    INFO    WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'(details)     javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web    13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.607   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2756    INFO    FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started(details)  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet   13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.607   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2757    INFO    Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Nov 13 17:49:... (details)   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext    13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.611   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2758    INFO    Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml](details)    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader   13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.612   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2759    INFO    Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory... (details)   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory    13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.651   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2760    INFO    Mapped URL path [/user*] onto handler 'userController'(details)     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping   13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.670   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2761    INFO    Mapped URL path [/index.htm] onto handler 'indexController'(details)    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping     13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.739   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2762    INFO    Mapped URL path [/user.htm] onto handler 'userController'(details)  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping     13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.740   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2763    INFO    FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 205 ms(details)  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet   13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.813   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2764    INFO    Loading application [SpringHibernateTuto2] at [/SpringHibernateTuto2](details)  javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web    13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.816   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2765    INFO    SpringHibernateTuto2 was successfully deployed in 1,007 milliseconds.(details)  javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin  13 nov. 2012 17:49:54.823   _ThreadID=2256;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2766    INFO    Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA(details)     org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.078   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2767    INFO    Hibernate 3.2.5(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.Environment   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.093   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2768    INFO    hibernate.properties not found(details)     org.hibernate.cfg.Environment   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.097   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2769    INFO    Bytecode provider name : cglib(details)     org.hibernate.cfg.Environment   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.099   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2770    INFO    using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.103   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2771    INFO    configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration     13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.175   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2772    INFO    Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml(details)     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration     13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.175   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2773    INFO    Reading mappings from resource : Model/User.hbm.xml(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration     13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.241   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2774    INFO    Configured SessionFactory: null(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration     13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.253   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2775    INFO    Mapping class: Model.User -> User(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder     13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.323   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2776    INFO    Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.342   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2777    INFO    Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)(details)     org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider    13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.407   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2778    INFO    Hibernate connection pool size: 20(details)     org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider    13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.407   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2779    INFO    autocommit mode: false(details)     org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider    13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.408   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2780    INFO    using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://inra3.seq.cng.fr:3306/EPGV_Interface?zeroDa... (details)   org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider    13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.408   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2781    INFO    connection properties: {user=mathieu, password=****}(details)   org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider    13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.408   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2782    INFO    MySQL, version: 5.1.61(details)     org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.417   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2783    INFO    JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} )(details)   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.417   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2784    INFO    Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect(details)  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.435   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2785    INFO    Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)(details)  org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory     13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.440   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2786    INFO    No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional secon... (details)   org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.443   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2787    INFO    Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.443   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2788    INFO    Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.443   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2789    INFO    JDBC batch size: 15(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.443   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2790    INFO    JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.444   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2791    INFO    Scrollable result sets: enabled(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.445   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2792    INFO    JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.445   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2793    INFO    Connection release mode: auto(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.445   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2794    INFO    Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.446   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2795    INFO    Default batch fetch size: 1(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.446   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2796    INFO    Generate SQL with comments: disabled(details)   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.447   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2797    INFO    Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled(details)     org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.447   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2798    INFO    Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled(details)   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.447   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2799    INFO    Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.447   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2800    INFO    Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory(details)    org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory     13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.451   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2801    INFO    Query language substitutions: {}(details)   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.451   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2802    INFO    JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled(details)     org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.451   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2803    INFO    Second-level cache: enabled(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.451   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2804    INFO    Query cache: disabled(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.451   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2805    INFO    Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.452   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2806    INFO    Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.452   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2807    INFO    Structured second-level cache entries: disabled(details)    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.452   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2808    INFO    Statistics: disabled(details)   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.459   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2809    INFO    Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled(details)     org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.459   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2810    INFO    Default entity-mode: pojo(details)  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.459   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2811    INFO    Named query checking : enabled(details)     org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.459   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2812    INFO    building session factory(details)   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.487   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2813    SEVERE  Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<i... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging   13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.626   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2814    WARNING     StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception ... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web    13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.627   _ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;

2815    INFO    cleaning up connection pool: jdbc:mysql://*****:3306/EPGV_Interface?zeroDateTimeBehavior=... (details)  org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider    13 nov. 2012 17:50:12.421   _ThreadID=3;_ThreadName=Thread-2;
```

And the detail of the sever error

Log Entry Detail

Timestamp

13 nov. 2012 17:50:01.626
Log Level

SEVERE
Logger

javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging
Name-Value Pairs

_ThreadID=189;_ThreadName=Thread-2;
Record Number

2813
Message ID

Complete Message

Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.(I)V

Is it helpful?
Do you need something else?

Comment: Can u post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Current exception does not say much. Do ex.printStackTrace() for exception in "System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);"

Comment: please post the complete stack trace here.

Comment: Thx for your replies. I don't have the access to the logs on the server, can i edit my code to display the full trace? I've tried a ex.printStackTrace() in the catch block from the factory creation without succes. (i'm also new to exception management ^^)

Comment: I've added the log from the glassfish admin console. I hope that will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv Please verify

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your asm version is incompatible with your Hibernate version. The relevant section of question is :

```
2813    SEVERE  Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<i... (details)
```

You need to check your asm version and hibnerate versions are compaitble. Check out the maven dependices/repositories..

Comment: Ok thx for these useful answers. Now i'll try to resolve this compatibility issues searching the web ^^

Answer (score 0):

just add cglib-nodep2.2 and remove cglib2.1.3, and remove older asm.jar from hibernate and do this for your hibernate only(first in classpath), 
leave the spring libs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where the application came up without any problems, however, when I tried to access the test resource, the server returned 404. The issue was in duplicate jars. I had include a hibernate jar and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa also contained hibernate, but a slightly different version. As soon as I started using spring-boot-started-data-jpa, it came back.