# CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes

Tags: spring

Am using Spring 3.1. War is not built using Maven. Its just a normal build. 
I have below jars in my class path.

```
antlr-runtime-3.0.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
org.apache.commons.logging.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M2.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M2.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.M2.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M2.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M2.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M2.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M2.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M2.jar
spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

I have below code,

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name="helloBean")
    public HelloWorld helloWorld()
    {
        return new HelloWorldImpl();
    }
}
```

When I run `main` method, am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes. Either add CGLIB to the classpath or remove the following @Configuration bean definitions: [appConfig]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:297)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:200)
```

To overcome this, if I add `cglib-2.1.jar`, am getting below exception..

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.Type
```

To overcome this, if I add `asm3.1.jar`, am getting below exception.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.
```

How can I overcome my initial exception - `CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes ?`

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> War is not built using Maven. Its just a normal build

Your problem exactly highlights why you should use Maven (or other similar dependency tool) -- congratulation on learning things the hard way. Libraries in Java world often have a very complex dependency tree and Maven can help resolve it all for you.

In your case, had you used maven you just need to include cglib dependency and all its transitive dependency (including asm) will be resolved for you

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks..But, is it not possible to solve this without switching to Maven? Few URLs are blocked by my company and when I tried building using Maven, there was a connection timeout..

Comment: The other way to solve this is you have to manually resolve all transitive dependency of cglib (and all other 3rd party libraries you decide to use) and include it to your classpath. Maven central repository search engine: http://search.maven.org can help you -- from there you can lookup what are dependencies of a particular artifact. Please note maven is a widely used infrastructure in a corporate environment. Larger corporate often have its own mirror of central repository (see Nexus). I strongly suggest you persuade your network admin to enable Maven

Comment: It should be independent to work without using Maven. Maven should not be a requirement.

Answer (score 5):

**Starting with Spring 3.2**, it is **no longer necessary** to add cglib as an explicit dependency.

*Reference:* http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/20/bootstraping-a-web-application-with-spring-3-1-and-java-based-configuration-part-1/#cglib_gone

This answer for those who wondered why their project running normally without cglib, and come to this page searching for info about cglib as me.

Answer (score 2):

CGLIB library is required in your program.
You can use Maven to download the dependency.

by xml as posted by gerrytan ie.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using maven (or other dependency tool), you can download the library from [CGLIB HomePage](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/releases).

Answer (score 1):

Use cglib-2.2.jar and asm-3.3.jar and add it your classpath