# Hibernate: error on asm jar working in one workspace , not in another workspace

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

This error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter
```

while running Hibernate mostly occurs when the `asm jar` is  *not updated* to the latest, and well be resolved by upgrading the asm jar version. *That's **not** my question*.

As well explained in this SO : [Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv)

ie: by excluding current usage

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

and include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**My specific question**/looking for some kind of confirmation:

I created a maven project with Spring, Hibernate

Spring: 3.2.2.RELEASE, Hibernate: 3.2.7.ga [The asm jar version resolved by Maven is asm1.5.3]

This is running good, no issues.

Recently another person reported an error on the same project with the same dependencies with the error stating 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter'

I understand, upgrading the asm version to the latest version might address this issue.
But since we have the same project and dependencies, **what else could be the trigger for this issue?**

Note: AFAIK there are no new dependencies in the other workspace, other than may be a higher JRE (mine is 1.6)

Answer (score 1):

Try to ask him clean local maven repo. Maybe there is some conflicts in dependencies versions.