# Exception with java.lang: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to develop a Restful Service with Hibernate in net beans 6.5.
I have also added `asm3.1.jar`
However I am still getting an exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:346)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
root cause

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.sun.jersey.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:123)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:722)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:692)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
root cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    se.xyz.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:28)
    se.xyz.main.CompaniesResource.getAllEmployees(CompaniesResource.java:368)
    se.xyz.main.CompaniesResource.getXml_getAllEmployees(CompaniesResource.java:129)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:85)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:123)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:722)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:692)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
    net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
    net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:117)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:295)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
    org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    se.xyz.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    se.xyz.main.CompaniesResource.getAllEmployees(CompaniesResource.java:368)
    se.xyz.main.CompaniesResource.getXml_getAllEmployees(CompaniesResource.java:129)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:85)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:123)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:722)
    com.sun.jersey.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:692)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv